# How do I declare and use variables in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, syntax

My main skills are with SQL Server, but I have been asked to do some tuning of an Oracle query. I have written the following SQL:

```
declare @startDate int
select @startDate = 20110501
```

And I get this error:

```
declare @startDate int
select @startDate = 20110501
Error at line 1
ORA-06550: line 1, column 9:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "@" when expecting one of the following:

   begin function package pragma procedure subtype type use
   <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> form
   current cursor
```

How do I declare and use variables in Oracle?

Comment: oracle is pure pain

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Inside pl/sql block:

```
declare
 startdate number;
begin
  select 20110501 into startdate from dual;
end;
/
```

using a bind variable:

```
var startdate number;
begin
  select 20110501 into :startdate from dual;
end;
/
```

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

```
SQL> print startdate

 STARTDATE
----------
  20110501
```

in a query:

```
select object_name 
from user_objects 
where created > to_date (:startdate,'yyyymmdd');  /*prefix the bind variable wïth ":" */
```

Comment: This unfortunately does not work for me.

var my_num NUMBER;  
BEGIN
    SELECT 12345 INTO my_num FROM dual;
END;
/
select * from my_table sa where sa.my_col = :my_num;

Comment: what error do you get? (just tested and works)

Comment: I actually tried the solution posted by Jon of All Trades and that worked perfectly for my needs -- i.e. using DEFINE and referencing the variable with &.

Answer (score 5):

SQL*Plus supports an additional format:

```
DEFINE StartDate = TO_DATE('2016-06-21');
DEFINE EndDate   = TO_DATE('2016-06-30');

SELECT
    *
FROM
    MyTable
WHERE
    DateField BETWEEN &StartDate and &EndDate;
```

Note the ampersands where the substitutions are to be performed within the query.

Comment: This worked for me in Toad for Oracle when using any of these functions: `Execute as script` or `Execute via Toad script runner` or `Execute via SQL*Plus`.  However, if you try running with the `Execute/compile statement at caret` it returns an error message: "ORA-009000: invalid SQL statement".

Comment: Works in SQL Developer too.

Answer (score 1):

In ORACLE SQL Developer 20.2.0.175, we can Run Script (F5):

```
DEFINE usr = 'YourName'; 
SELECT * FROM Department WHERE created_by = '&usr';
```