# I'm trying to use a variable in Oracle PL/SQL, but I'm getting an error. What's wrong here?

Tags: oracle, plsql, syntax

I come from an SQL Server background and I'm trying to figure out how to use Oracle PL/SQL variables.  I'm trying to declare a variable and then select that variable.  It sounds simple, but I am doing something wrong.  Here's my code:

```
declare
    num number;
begin
    num := 64;        
    select num from dual; --error here
end;
/
```

This gives me an error message that says: "PLS-00428: an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement".

I tried a few other permutations of this but each gives me an error:

```
declare
    num number;
begin
    num := 64;
end;
select num from dual; --"num" invalid identifier
/
```

And this one also gives me an error.

```
declare
    num number;
begin
    num := 64;
end;
/
select num from dual; --"num" invalid identifier
```

Based on Mihai's comment, I tried putting the declare after the begin, but that threw errors as well:

```
begin
declare
    num number;
    num := 64; --encountered symbol "=" when expecting ...
end;
/
select num from dual; --"num" invalid identifier
```

---

For reference: here's how I would do this in SQL Server.  It may not be clear, but the scope of the @num variable below is the file containing the declaration.  This variable is not global.

```
declare @num int = 64
select @num
```

I am doing this is DBArtisan.  Note that this question is similar to [this one here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3652/how-do-i-declare-and-use-variables-in-oracle), but I'm also asking how to *use* the variable.  And I'm not interested in bind variables (I don't think).  I want to write one-off queries like this: `select * from employee where manager_id = mgrID` with the mgrID being a variable that I declare.

Comment: That didn't do it.  I added that example to my post.  I think it's Oracle's syntax to put the declaration before the begin.  Thanks anyway.

Comment: I believe your 'select' statement is confusing people; it appears you simply wanted to echo back the variable contents/value. In that case, the dbms_output.put_line()    syntax will work [once the PL/SQL block is evaluated.]

Comment: @JasonInVegas, You're probably right.  I submitted an answer below that uses `with` to simulate variables, and it does more than echo a variable.  Are you familiar with PL/SQL?  Do you know a better way to write the query in my answer?

Answer (score 3):

I think these answers are all getting a) way too complicated, and b) off-track relative to what user2023861 wants to accomplish:

"I am trying to declare a variable, then select that variable." means two different things in either PL/SQL or in SQLplus, and perhaps two more things in DBArtisan.   To accomplish the objective in SQLplus, use "Substitution variables"...[excellent background is found here.](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia#9)

My example, doesn't precisely follow your SQL Server T-SQL example, but it's close and is NOT procedural (read: no anonymous PL/SQL block.)

**PL/SQL with Substitution variables:**

```
DEFINE min_salary = 1000
DEFINE mgrID = 7

select *
from employees
where
    salary > &min_salary
    and mgrID = &mgrID
;
```

All at the SQL-Plus prompt....from my fictional employees table, I got this result:

```
    SALARY      MGRID
---------- ----------
      2000          7
      1001          7
2 row selected.
```

If you want to make this semi-procedural, then you use BIND Variables and the declarative syntax of PL/SQL similar to T-SQL. (In my opinion this is a HUGE waste of effort, but is included to help clarify variable types.)

**SQLPlus using PL/SQL Bind variables:**

```
 VARIABLE   v_in_min_salary number;
 VARIABLE   v_mgrID         number;    /* vars are defined within SQL+ */
 VARIABLE   v_out_salary    number;
 VARIABLE   v_out_mgrID     number; 

BEGIN
    :v_in_min_salary    := 1000;   /* vars are assigned values in PL/SQL */ 
    :v_mgrID            := 7; 

 select salary, mgrID 
  into :v_out_salary, :v_out_mgrID 
  from employees 
  where salary > :v_in_min_salary and mgrID = :v_mgrID
 ;

end;
/

PRINT :v_in_min_salary   /* here the in and out vars are displayed  */
PRINT :v_mgrID
PRINT :v_out_salary
PRINT :v_out_mgrID
```

**Fully-procedural approach using PL/SQL:**

```
set serveroutput on;  /* environment setting within SQLplus to see output */
DECLARE
   v_in_min_salary number   := 1000;
   v_mgrID    number        :=7; 
   v_out_salary number;
   v_out_mgrID    number; 

BEGIN
  SELECT salary, mgrID 
    into :v_out_salary, :v_out_mgrID 
    from employees 
    where salary > :v_in_min_salary and mgrID = :v_mgrID
  ;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Salary Output is= '||:v_out_salary);
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Manager ID = '||:v_out_mgrID);
END;
/
```

So, when do I use each case?  I use SQLplus Substitution variables 75% of the time when I write SQL scripts that I want to parameterize the input for. Executing a script at the SQLplus prompt allows passing inbound arguments, so my favorite Substitution variables are &1 and &2 as in the following example:

```
   @get_table_size.sql <schema> <table_name>  
        which in practice becomes 
   @get_table_size jason employees
```

and executes SQL code similar to

```
SELECT extents 
  FROM all_tables 
  WHERE UPPER(table_owner) = upper('&1')  /* inbound first argument */
  and UPPER(table_name) = upper('&2')     /* inbound 2nd argument   */
;
```

Notice how the inbound arguments are assigned into substitution variables, then used in the SQL statement.  I never use the middle example, and I always use the 3rd examples (procedural PL/SQL) when writing functions, procs, and packages.

Comment: --PS I am interested in DBArtisan and the differences it may have when using variables, so I downloaded the free trial and will post any relevant differences once they are uncovered.

Comment: I tried your `PL/SQL with Substitution variables` example and I get an error message that says `ORA-01008: not all variables bound`.  I got the same error message with your other two examples.  I don't think the last two examples would work for me if I wanted a result set, like this TSQL one `select * from employee where manager_id = @mgrID`  Maybe it's a DBArtisan thing

Answer (score 2):

Your first attempt is the correct syntax for an anonymous PL/SQL block

The error message

> *an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement*

told you precisely what the problem is.

You can't just "select" inside a stored procedure (or a PL/SQL block) and then have the result magically "returned" from there. This is a fundamental difference between PL/SQL and T-SQL.

If you want a procedure to return a result you either need a REF CURSOR as an out parameter or you need to create a function that returns a result set. But in both cases you can't just call the procedure/function. The caller needs to consume the result somehow if the procedure returns REF CURSOR or explicitly use it instead of a table, e.g. `select * from  table(my_function());`

Comment: When I use a REF CURSOR or create a function, is this something I will have to delete when I'm done with it?  Or does it go out of scope?  And do you have a simple example?  I'm having trouble finding one simple example script that contains all of these ideas succinctly.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an option I put together that both gets the job done and avoids ugly boilerplate code:

```
with vars as
(
    select 
        1000  v_min,
        7     v_mgrID
    from dual
)

select *
from employees
where 
    salary > (select v_min from vars)
    and mgrID = (select v_mgrID from vars)
```

This may not be the most performant code, but it's easy to understand.  I have found that the documentation for PL/SQL in regards to reading from and writing to variables extremely poor.  I'd be happy to be proven wrong, but I can't find a simple example of PL/SQL code that contains the same concepts exhibited in the following TSQL code:

```
declare @min_salary int = 1000
declare @mgrID int = 7

select *
from employees
where
    salary > @min_salary
    and mgrID = @mgrID
```

With this code, I don't need to know about cursors, or loops, or code blocks.

Comment: Which SQL client are you using? In the Oracle world such a query parameter is usually handled by the SQL client (e.g. by using `&v_min` in SQL*Plus. See the manual for examples: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_five.htm#i1211130 I believe the same works in SQL Developer. Other clients might have other ways of doing that.

Comment: DBArtisan 9.6.1